# Terminal is showing password when typing so fast

Tags: 16.04, password

I'm getting a problem right now. When I'm typing so fast on terminal it will show my password.

Any suggestions. Thanks a lot ;)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmMp7edgEI0

Comment: what terminal is this?

Comment: Do you mean when you use `sudo` and then it prompts for password?

Comment: Yes correct. When I use sudo then it prompts for password. But after I inputted password maybe it needs 1 second for hiding.

Comment: That underline is odd. Do you have some input method enabled?

Comment: it should not show anything, and it won't in a normal case. in your case I would check `alias` if there is an alias for sudo, and if not check `sudo cat /etc/sudoers` and compare with this standard one http://pastebin.com/2MRF7NX4

Comment: I can't thank you enough . Because I'm using another input method so I got the problem.

Comment: Thanks all. It's working now cuz I'm using third party keyboard.